# Are DLLs the only way to "black box" your code?

Tags: dll, architecture, .net-3.5, black-box

My DAL and BLL are going to be used as base classes for Webforms that are similar. However, I want these base classes to be "hidden" away and just inherited from. If there needs to be a change it's done from one place and the dlls (or other solution) is just redistributed. I know you can do such a thing with DLLs, but I was wondering if .NET 3.5 has other ways of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not really. Are you looking for more efficiency? ease of use? Distributing DLLs is going to be a good way of keeping your code separate while allowing them to include it in an application and use it as a base class. .NET calls them "assemblies" but it's really just another DLL users can include.

Comment: Ah. So assemblies and dlls are NOT different? Just two names for the same thing?

Comment: yeah. it's their term for it. an exe is also an assembly, just a different kind. it takes a bit of explaining, so here's a link to the wiki article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_assembly